# Fastest way to find the dimension of a Lie algebra generated by a finite set of operators?

Tags: lie-algebras

Suppose I have a finite set of operators and I would like to know the dimension of the Lie algebra that they generate (but do not require a basis). The only method I can find is to recursively compute all pairwise commutators from the set until it stops growing, as described in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936881/computational-procedure-to-find-the-basis-of-a-lie-algebra-generated-by-a-finite).

Is the above procedure the best we can do, or is there a quicker method?